# Channel error on connection rabbitmq, celery and django

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

> =ERROR REPORT==== 18-Aug-2018::11:38:19 === Channel error on connection <0.17949.0> (IP:50872 -> IP:5672, vhost: 'myhost', user: 'myuser'), channel 1: {amqp_error,access_refused, "access to exchange 'celeryev' in vhost 'myhost' refused for user 'user'", 'exchange.declare'}

Following above is the error i am facing right now.

I had already running AWS instance, took a snapshot and put new django code over it. Run the celery task over it and facing this error in the rabbitmq server logs.

When check the snapshot there was no user and vhost. So i added the exact same name and password user and vhost. and set the permissions as administrator. And still keep facing this issue.

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So what was my problem, actually the permissions were not set accurately. What i did from rabbitmq web interface i set the same permissions as the guest login, and it just start working fine.